# Using to_json triggers extra queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, rails-activerecord

I have a certain ActiveRecord scope that joins my `appointment` and `client` tables. When I use it, there's just one query:

```
1.9.2p290 :071 > reload!;Appointment.for_day(Time.zone.today).full.first
Reloading...
  Appointment Load (6.9ms)  SELECT "appointment".* FROM "appointment" JOIN client ON client.id = appointment.client_id
 LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.appointment_id = appointment.id WHERE (start_time between '2013-01-26 05:00:00.000000' and '2013-01-27 04:59:59.000000' and is_cancelled = false) ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 1
 => #<Appointment id: 10137, start_time: "2013-01-26 13:00:00", created_at: "2012-07-16 18:01:21", updated_at: "2012-07-16 18:01:21", stylist_id: 88, client_id: 398, recurring: false, appointment_id: nil, is_cancelled: false, tip: #<BigDecimal:107ea1d68,'0.0',9(18)>, repeats_every_how_many_weeks: 1, recurrence_rule_hash: "qkebvqfsprmkbcsccsifbbumazooampyxzkyehqommbjmdsmmc", can_repeat: true, notes: "", time_block_type_id: 2, length: 60>
```

When I take that same thing and run it through `to_json`, I get two extra queries:

```
1.9.2p290 :072 > reload!;Appointment.for_day(Time.zone.today).full.first.to_json
Reloading...
  Appointment Load (6.7ms)  SELECT "appointment".* FROM "appointment" JOIN client ON client.id = appointment.client_id
 LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.appointment_id = appointment.id WHERE (start_time between '2013-01-26 05:00:00.000000' and '2013-01-27 04:59:59.000000' and is_cancelled = false) ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "client".* FROM "client" WHERE "client"."id" = 398 LIMIT 1
  Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "address".* FROM "address" WHERE "address"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
 => "{\"appointment_id\":null,\"can_repeat\":true,\"client_id\":398,\"created_at\":\"2012-07-16T14:01:21-04:00\",\"id\":10137,\"is_cancelled\":false,\"length\":60,\"notes\":\"\",\"recurrence_rule_hash\":\"qkebvqfsprmkbcsccsifbbumazooampyxzkyehqommbjmdsmmc\",\"recurring\":false,\"repeats_every_how_many_weeks\":1,\"start_time\":\"2013-01-26T08:00:00-05:00\",\"stylist_id\":88,\"time_block_type_id\":2,\"tip\":\"0.0\",\"updated_at\":\"2012-07-16T14:01:21-04:00\",\"client\":{\"active\":true,\"address_id\":10,\"created_at\":\"2012-05-22T11:48:44-04:00\",\"email\":\"\",\"id\":398,\"name\":\"No client\",\"notes\":\"\",\"phone\":\"\",\"salon_id\":29,\"updated_at\":\"2012-05-22T11:48:44-04:00\",\"wants_email_reminders\":false}}"
```

It's frustrating that ActiveRecord wants to do another query on the `client` table, since I already did the `appointment`-`client` join for it. I have many more associations on `Appointment` that I'll need to include, and having a separate query for each one is not acceptable.

How can I convert a resultset to JSON without triggering a bunch of extra queries?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My problem came from a bad design, and I fixed my bad design by using [RABL](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails).